# String compare is not working

Tags: javascript, string

why I am getting Not matched everytime..
what is wrong with this code

```
var CourseDesc = 'Master of Computer Application'

var str = CourseDesc.split(" ");
alert(str[0]);
var str2 = 'Master';

if(str == str2){
    alert("Matched");
}else{
    alert("Not Matched");
}
```

Anybody faced this??

Comment: str is an array, not a string

Comment: I think you should modify the condition in your if-statement. From str == str2 to str[0] == str2

Comment: Just  addition over Aruns comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/pLmuv0sm/

Comment: Seems someone has their grumpy pants on today.  I don't see anything that merits the amount of down voting that's happening on this page.  It might have been a simple error by the OP, but that does not make it a bad or unuseful question.  And most the answers are reasonable responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.Split method returns an array that contains the substrings.
So, your `str` variable is an Array not a String.

**`if(str[0] == str2)`**

```
var CourseDesc = 'Master of Computer Application'

var str = CourseDesc.split(" ");
alert(str[0]);
var str2 = 'Master';

if(str[0] == str2){
    alert("Matched");
}else{
    alert("Not Matched");
}
```

## [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rts187my/)

Comment: emphasis on `if(str[0] == str2){` @bugyt should probably bold that part.

Comment: allright :) thank you

Comment: @bugyt Oh sorry guys.. I didnt notice array.. stupidity.. Thanks for noticed..

Answer (score -2):

It's not clear from the question if the OP is only interested in matching the first word in the primary string, but, if you are only interested to find out if the keyword (str2) is anywhere in the results of the split of the first string (which is, as has been pointed out, an array), you can just look for an index.

Alternatively, as demonstrated in the second block of code in the demo, you can just match against the original string without splitting:

```js
var CourseDesc = 'Master of Computer Application'

var str = CourseDesc.split(" ");
var str2 = 'Master';

if (str.indexOf(str2) != -1) {
  alert("Matched");
} else {
  alert("Not Matched");
}

var str3 = 'Master of Computer Application';
var str4 = 'Master';

if (str3.match(str4)) {
  console.log("Matched");
} else {
  console.log("Not Matched");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var CourseDesc = 'Master of Computer Application'

var str = CourseDesc.split(" ");
alert(str[0]);
var str2 = 'Master';

if(str == str2){ 
 alert("Matched");
}else{
 alert("Not Matched");
}
```

str is array if you want to match CourseDesc with any keyword you can try the for loop

```
var CourseDesc = 'Master of Computer Application'

var str = CourseDesc.split(" ");

var str2 = 'Master';

for(var i=0 ;i<str.length; i++){
  alert(str[i]);
   if(str[i] == str2){ 
     alert("Matched");
   }else{
     alert("Not Matched");
   }
}
```